# SQL RESTORE FILELISTONLY query brings error in event viewer - BackupIoRequest::ReportIoError: read failure on backup device

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, metadata, vss

I use the following query:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM disk = N'E:\Tmp\metadata2012.metadata' with CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR
--or even like that
--RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM disk = N'E:\Tmp\metadata2012.metadata'
GO
```

output:

```
LogicalName                                                                                                                      PhysicalName                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     Type FileGroupName                                                                                                                    Size                 MaxSize              FileId               CreateLSN                               DropLSN                                 UniqueId                             ReadOnlyLSN                             ReadWriteLSN                            BackupSizeInBytes    SourceBlockSize FileGroupId LogGroupGUID                         DifferentialBaseLSN                     DifferentialBaseGUID                 IsReadOnly IsPresent TDEThumbprint                              SnapshotUrl
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ------------------------------------ --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- -------------------- --------------- ----------- ------------------------------------ --------------------------------------- ------------------------------------ ---------- --------- ------------------------------------------ ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dbRestoreToTime                                                                                                                  C:\dbRestoreToTime2012.mdf                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       D    PRIMARY                                                                                                                          3145728              35184372080640       1                    0                                       0                                       207A4430-91A0-4EFF-B9AB-44370D91D8E5 0                                       0                                       2424832              512             1           NULL                                 32000000041100037                       F0DC3522-3C58-4AD0-A0BF-40CA3EE96793 0          1         NULL                                       NULL
dbRestoreToTime_log                                                                                                              C:\dbRestoreToTime_log2012.ldf                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   L    NULL                                                                                                                             1048576              2199023255552        2                    0                                       0                                       E83E06CD-2151-40EB-8660-DB3C3D58C334 0                                       0                                       0                    512             0           NULL                                 0                                       00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 0          1         NULL                                       NULL
dbRestoreToTime-2_log                                                                                                            C:\dbRestoreToTime_log2012-2.ldf                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 L    NULL                                                                                                                             1048576              2199023255552        3                    31000000007400001                       0                                       FE7D0324-6D8D-40BE-927A-6B9916505FD7 0                                       0                                       0                    512             0           NULL                                 0                                       00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 0          1         NULL                                       NULL
MyTestFileStore                                                                                                                  C:\FILESTORE2012                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 S    TestFileStore                                                                                                                    0                    0                    65537                31000000009800001                       0                                       E9467C76-B305-4355-82F9-980DADDA7984 0                                       0                                       0                    512             2           NULL                                 32000000041100037                       F0DC3522-3C58-4AD0-A0BF-40CA3EE96793 0          1         NULL                                       NULL

(4 rows affected)


Completion time: 2021-10-25T18:12:18.4750926+02:00
```

It works as expected, but unfortunately it generates the following error in the windows event viewer:

```
BackupIoRequest::ReportIoError: read failure on backup device 'E:\Tmp\metadata2012.metadata'. Operating system error 87(The parameter is incorrect.).
```

I can restore my database to a specific point in time and it works perfectly (there're several more steps required for that like attaching DB in `norecovery` state, creating `VDI` device and applying logs but it's out of scope - `DBCC` check gives no error on restored DB). The only one thing is the error in the windows event viewer. Do you have any idea why it's happening ?

`SQL VSS` makes `metadata2012.metadata` and it's part of the following `backupcomponents.xml`:
(It's the metadata which I use for my `RESTORE FILELISTONLY` query)

```
<COMPONENT logicalPath="DUBA\MSSQL2012" componentName="dbRestoreToTime" componentType="filegroup" backupStamp="CAAAADmvi82s6s4B">
     <BACKUP_METADATA xmlns="" metadata="BCgAAFRBUEUAAAMAjAAOAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIAhwUSCTobBQAAAAEAAAACAAMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALABeAAAEABIfdvUZoAFNAGkAYwByAG8AcwBvAGYAdAAgAFMAUQBMACAAUwBlAHIAdgBlAHIAAAAAAAAAUkFJRAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA7BfP7bECNc6pLnEmvZsDJx/StAADwAQABAAEAAAAAAAEAAABTUEFEAAAAACYDAAAAAAAAAAAAADQXAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABTRk1CAAAAgAAEDgEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABCBdwAAAAAAAABIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAU1NFVAAAAACgAA4BAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAVAGQAAgDLBgQAAAAAAAAAABIBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACYAegAACAAAAAAAAB929RmgCwAQAAIAAFHZN5LevEhPgpfziPH6tRIAAAAAAABOAFQAIABBAFUAVABIAE8AUgBJAFQAWQBcAFMAWQBTAFQARQBNAFNQQUQAAAAASgMAAAAAAAAAAAAAWBcAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFZPTEIAAAAAWAAOAQAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIATgwCAAAABABJAAAATQAIAE0AH3b1GaBDADoARABVAEIAQQAAAABTUEFEAAAAAJIDAAAAAAAAAAAAAIAXAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABNU0NJAAAAADgADgEAAAAAAAAAAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACADobAAAAAE1RQ0kAAAAAHhUAAAAAAAAAAAAAEA1TQ0lOygEAAAICAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAA0CAALCQAAACEAAAAQAAAAOwAhAAAAKwAAAAEAIQAAABAAAAA7ACAAAACbAQAAJQAfdvT2yB929RmgH3b1GaBENAEAbgYAwgIANiUAAAAAAB4AkAEcAK4BAAAAAAkEAAABAAMASacT6dlhdkq7CCFoHzgzwSAAAAAhAAAAKwAAAAEAAAA+U6UnS2KdT7StxL+Z+bkoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACI13PBYPNBKoL9Ayj7pZ5MJBNAANAAAAD5TpSdLYp1PtK3Ev5n5uSgAAAEAAAABACAAAABTAQAAjgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA2JQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAZABiAFIAZQBzAHQAbwByAGUAVABvAFQAaQBtAGUARABVAEIAQQBcAE0AUwBTAFEATAAyADAAMQAyAFNGR0nuAAAAEAAAAAEAAAAOAOAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAhAAAAEAAAADsAAAAhAAAAKwAAAAEAAAAhAAAAEAAAADsAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAUwEAAI4AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIQAAACsAAAABAAAAPlOlJ0tinU+0rcS/mfm5KAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUABSAEkATQBBAFIAWQBTRkdJ+gAAABAAAAACAAAAGgDgAAIAAABKcXKw2q7mS6T9P9DFK9WtAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFQAZQBzAHQARgBpAGwAZQBTAHQAbwByAGUAU0ZJTlYEAACEAAAAAAAAAAAgAAABAAAAKAEAAAEAAAAAAgAAAQAAAAAAMAAAAAAAHgAEBDQAIgQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA4P///x8AAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAwAAAAAAAA4P///x8AAAAAMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAmwEAACUAAAAiNdzwWDzQSqC/QMo+6WeTMER6IKCR/065q0Q3DZHY5SEAAAAQAAAAOwAAAAAAAAAhAAAAKwAAAAEAAAAAAAAAIQAAABAAAAA7AAAAAAAAAAAAJQAAAAAAAAAAAIA55K+r6s4BAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQwBkAGIAUgBlAHMAdABvAHIAZQBUAG8AVABpAG0AZQBDADoAXABkAGIAUgBlAHMAdABvAHIAZQBUAG8AVABpAG0AZQAyADAAMQAyAC4AbQBkAGYAU0ZJTmYEAAAMAAAAAAAAAAAgAAACAAAAAAAAAAIAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAJgAEBDwAKgQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIAAAoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAA4P///x8AAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAzQY+6FEh60CGYNs8PVjDNCEAAAAQAAAAOwAAAAAAAAAhAAAAKwAAAAEAAAAAAAAAIQAAABAAAAA7AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQwBkAGIAUgBlAHMAdABvAHIAZQBUAG8AVABpAG0AZQBfAGwAbwBnAEMAOgBcAGQAYgBSAGUAcwB0AG8AcgBlAFQAbwBUAGkAbQBlAF8AbABvAGcAMgAwADEAMgAuAGwAZABmAFNGSU5uBAAADAAAAAAAAAAAIAAAAwAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAIAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAACoABARAAC4EAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAAKAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAOD///8fAAAAABAAAAAAAB8AAABKAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACQDff6Nbb5AknprmRZQX9chAAAAEAAAADsAAAAAAAAAIQAAACsAAAABAAAAAAAAACEAAAAQAAAAOwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEMAZABiAFIAZQBzAHQAbwByAGUAVABvAFQAaQBtAGUALQAyAF8AbABvAGcAQwA6AFwAZABiAFIAZQBzAHQAbwByAGUAVABvAFQAaQBtAGUAXwBsAG8AZwAyADAAMQAyAC0AMgAuAGwAZABmAFNGSU5CBAAAhAAAAAAAAAAAIAAAAQABAAAAAAAHAAAAAAIAAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB4ABAQgACIEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB8AAABiAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIAAAAJsBAAAlAAAAIjXc8Fg80Eqgv0DKPulnk3Z8RukFs1VDgvmYDa3aeYQhAAAAEAAAADsAAAAAAAAAIQAAACsAAAABAAAAAAAAACEAAAAQAAAAOwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAOeSvq+rOAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEMATQB5AFQAZQBzAHQARgBpAGwAZQBTAHQAbwByAGUAQwA6AFwARgBJAEwARQBTAFQATwBSAEUAMgAwADEAMgBNUVNTAAAAANEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAM8DAAAFAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAEABAAAAAdR564wAAgAAwAAADEAAAAAAAAAADAAgwCDAIcAiQCNAJEAlQCVAJUAlQCVAJUAlQCZAJkAmQCjAL8AyQDTAN0A7QDtAP0AAQELAQsBCwEbASUBOQFNAVUBXQFlAXUBdQF9AYcBkQGtAa0BrQGtAa0BrQGtAbcBSacT6dlhdkq7CCFoHzgzwQEAAQACAAAAAAD/////AAAAAAgEAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAfAAAAYgAAAAEAIAAAAJsBAAAlACI13PBYPNBKoL9Ayj7pZ5N2fEbpBbNVQ4L5mA2t2nmEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP//////////AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//////////8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKdoBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFNQQUQAAAAAlgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAhBQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAh98LT"/>
</COMPONENT>
```

Comment: So what happens if you *don't* pass `CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR`, and how exactly do you know the restore "works perfectly"? A restore actually verifies very little, especially since most backups are not made with checksums (as that's not the default). Do a `DBCC CHECKDB` on your restored database, and see what happens if the restore runs from another device. It's possible the error is "harmless" and a result of some odd driver interaction or a corner case in the engine, but then again it's also possible it's not harmless at all and the result of a subtle problem that can result in corruption.

Comment: @JeroenMostert same result if I do not pass `CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR`. "works perfectly" means that I can restore the DB to a specific point time and make the DB online.(I ommited all other steps norecovery, vdi, applaying logs, recovery etc)

Comment: Presumably E: is local storage and not a network/mapped drive?

Comment: @Stu it's the mapped drive(I can even put the `metadata2012.bak` into sql default location - result is the same )

Comment: If it *is* a mapped drive then this points to a network issue.

Comment: @Stu sorry for misleading, I wanted to say that it's named local drive

Comment: @JeroenMostert DBCC check gives no error on restored DB

Comment: Do you have an antivirus or malware detection application installed? If so, what happens if you exclude file extensions of type `*.metadata`?

Comment: @RandolphWest will check antivirus(I use eset). Regarding `*.metadata` it does not matter whether it has an extension or not. I tried with back - same result

Comment: I think you have to take this with whoever is producing that file. We are used to use backup files created by the BACKUP command. This is something different, considering VSS is involved. If for instance this is produced by Veeam, then I would go that route. Perhaps it isn't supported to take a Veeam (?) VSS backup, convert it into a SQL server backup file? Or perhaps Veeam (?) doesn't do it correctly? Or do you have more details/documentation regarding what is actually going on (the whole picture)...?

Comment: @RandolphWest i did the same with disabled antivirus and got the same result

Comment: @TiborKaraszi details of the process is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/sql-server-vss-writer-backup-guide?view=sql-server-ver15#snapshot-creation-workflow) and [metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/sql-server-vss-writer-backup-guide?view=sql-server-ver15#sql-writer-metadata-document)

Comment: I figured it is a VSS backup. Where you lose me here is that you try to do a FILELISTONLY on the meta-data for a VSS backup. Do you have a documentation that states that this is supported?

Comment: @TiborKaraszi no I do not

Comment: I think that you quite simply do something that wasn't meant to do. Hence the error.